# TFS Fails to build a project containing Microsoft Fakes

Tags: visual-studio-2012, microsoft-fakes

After adding Fakes framework to the test project after each check in I get the following error:

```
Error   33  The last access/last write time on file "XYZ.1.5.5.0.Fakes.dll" cannot be set. Access to the path 'XYZ.1.5.5.0.Fakes.dll' is denied.    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Fakes\Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.targets  137 5   ABCProjectName
Error   34  The last access/last write time on file "XYZ.1.5.5.0.Fakes.fakesconfig" cannot be set. Access to the path 'XYZ.1.5.5.0.Fakes.fakesconfig' is denied.    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Fakes\Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.targets  137 5   ABCProjectName
```

Also after I check in VS marks both of the files mentioned above as read-only. After this happens, building the project on the local machine fails with exactly the same errors.

Comment: Are you using the Visual Studio Test Runner or MSTest? Fakes won't work with MSTest.

Answer (score 3):

You should generally not check-in fakes dlls into tfs. Let fakes create them during build. If you're worried about the performance hit of creating fakes dlls during build time which is a valid concern, then you should read and do what's suggested in [Optimizing build times](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708916.aspx#BKMK_Optimizing_build_times).

Comment: Can you setup so the build service creates Faked DLLs?

Comment: @Vitalij is right. You should let us know how to do that, because I have the exact same problem as him, and I have Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate installed on my build server.

Comment: You need to install the version of Visual Studio that includes Fakes on your build server. Fakes was only available in Ultimate edition initially but a decision was made to include it in Premium as well. So at the very minimum, you need to install Visual Studio Premium on your build server.

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate installed on the build server, without luck.